# What can I use to protect my walls from marks and scratches?

Tags: drywall, paint, scratches

I store my skis against the wall, and over time the wall ends up with black marks and scratches from the minor rubbing from the skis. It's removable with a Mr. Clean Magic Eraser, but I would rather protect the wall.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't screw into or damage the wall. I have thought of helicopter tape, but I'm not sure if that would rip off paint when removed. I need a strip about a foot high and multiple feet long, roughly at eye level.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is too broad a question for our Q&A forum, especially with so little information.

Comment: To reinforce what Daniel said, the answer is "almost anything". I'd probably install two pine rails, the upper one having pairs of hooks to hold the skis and the lower to act as a bumper.

Comment: Because satin latex paint over drywall is actually quite fragile, and is not made to be handled/touched/rubbed against.  Unless you get lucky with cleaning, generally the answer is repaint.   A problem in America is something I call "the war on utility space". Historically you'd keep that stuff in your garage, utility room or basement where the walls were open 2x4, cinderblock or plywood, and that's where you would store stuff like that.

Comment: I disagree; there is plenty of information, to form a valid answer, that supports the OPs desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the Command™ no damage wall hangers with a strip of canvas between 2 of these hangers to prevent scuffing of our entry where my son used to put his snowboard. At the end of the season pull the adhesive and they release with no damage to the wall. At his home now he found some of the strips that hold a wood piece he never takes it down so I don't know if they stay up for multiple years if it will affect the wall but it is a way to protect the wall without drilling.

Comment: Canvas is a great idea.  You could also use a sheet of clear acrylic from the hardware store if that fits your decor better.  You can use a few Command adhesive strips directly on the acrylic, without needing to buy the Command hooks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire industry devoted to wall protection. Search for [Rigid Sheet Wall Protection](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rigid%20Sheet%20Wall%20Protection&client=firefox-b-1&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm2ICdh7LfAhWMo4MKHV7uCKEQ_AUICSgA&biw=1360&bih=673&dpr=1).

As far as fastening it without screwing, regular 3M double sided tape should suffice.